# How to assign values to some data grid view column when dgv is binded

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a data grid view which is binded to a list. List is an object list

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>();

User user = new User(){
    Name = "Diana",
    Age = "37"
}

userList.Add(user);

myDataGridView.DataSource = null;

myDataGridView.DataSource = userList();
myDataGridView.Columns["Name"].DataPropertyName = "Name";
myDataGridView.Columns["Age"].DataPropertyName = "Age";
```

But i have one more column Which is "Permission"

I want to check if a user is age > 18 then permission columns value for related user's row will be a string "Valid"
There is no permission property in my user class and I don't want to add it. How can I do this?

Comment: You could try using an expression to calculate the value of "Permission", theres several examples on SO including this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097370/calculation-in-datagridview-column

Comment: or another here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257674/winforms-datagridview-calculated-field-change-event

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is doable, however there are some drawbacks to doing it the way you describe. First off, introducing a new column to the grid that “IS NOT” part of the data source will require the code to “manage” that column. Meaning that if the grid is sorted/filtered etc.… your code is going to have to go through the grid and manage the “age > 18” column. I am guessing you may be looking for something that will do this automatically.

I am curious as to why you need this column since the “age” column is already present and I would not think that the user would be challenged by “visually seeing” the age column and determining if the value is over 18. Possibly coloring the cell for values less than 18 instead of “adding” a new column. Just a thought.

In addition, I am not sure “why” you do not want to add the “permission” property to the class. It is a “computed” value from the existing data, therefore, there is no need to actually keep the value in the original data source. What happens if you add the following code to the `User` class? I am betting it will display the “permission” value as you describe.

```
public string Permission {
  get {
    if (Age > 18)
      return "Valid";
    else
      return "Invalid";
  }
}
```

This is one approach, however, using a `List<T>` as a `DataSource` for the grid has some drawbacks. Namely, the user will not be able to “add” new rows to the grid without more coding on your part. That is why I recommend you take a look at a `BindingSource` or `BindingList<User>` as an alternative to the `List<User>` … these `Binding` controls will make it easier to handle the adding of new rows, filtering, sorting, etc.